# How to store Images in backend for E-Commerce website?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, e-commerce

I am trying to build a ecommerce web application where user can post adds to sell product. I plan to ask for an IdProof to verify the users Identity. How should I be storing the images of products they post as well as the pdf of their Id proof?
I am building the application using Spring Boot, Hibernate and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use s3 buckets for storing the files and images and referencing the data by a unique id, that can later be matched depending on user identity.

Resourc
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deliver-content-faster/